# How to loop through Kendo Dropdown

Tags: kendo-ui

I have filled a KendoDropdown with few data.

Now when I give an input in the Kendo textbox and click a button, I should be able to loop through the items in the dropdown to check if the input value is already exist in the Dropdown. 
Please any one tell me how can I achieve this in jquery?. 
Any sample code?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
$($("#dropDownName").data("kendoDropDownList").dataItems()).each(function () {
        if (this.Value == 10) { //use your logic here
            //do your stuff
        }  
    });
```